# Blog engine or somesuch

Tags: php, beginner, classes, mysqli

Would someone tell how I can improve this piece of code?

```
<?php


include_once './Core/Database/Db_connection.php';

class Post extends Db_connection {

    private $totalPage;
    private $per_page;
    private $page;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function set_per_page($per_page) {
        $this->per_page = $per_page;
    }

    function set_total_page($total) {
        $this->totalPage = $total;
    }

    function set_page($page) {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    function get_page() {
        return $this->page;
    }

    function get_per_page() {
        return $this->per_page;
    }

    function get_total_page() {
        return $this->totalPage;
    }

    function counts($cats) {
        $sql = "select count(post_id) from Post where category='$cats'";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        return $rows;
    }

    function cats() {
        $sql = "select  distinct category from Post ";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $row[] = $rows;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        $this->closeDb();
        return $row;
    }

    function postByCats($cats) {
        if ($cats == NULL)
            return $this->Posts($cats);
        $sql = "select * from Post  where category='$cats'";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            $tuts[] = $row;
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        $this->closeDb();
        return $tuts;
    }

    function Posts($many = NULL) {
        $sql = "select count(post_id) from Post";
        $per = $this->set_per_page(3);
        $query = $this->query($sql);
        $num = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $numrows = $num[0];
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
            $num = intval($_GET['page']);
            $this->set_page($num);
        } else {
            $num = 1;
            $this->set_page($num);
        }

        //offset and number per page
        $total = ceil($numrows / $this->get_per_page());
        $this->set_total_page($total);
        $num_off = $this->get_per_page();
        if ($this->get_page() > $this->get_total_page()) {
            $this->set_page($this->get_total_page());
        }
        if ($this->get_page() < 1) {
            $this->set_page(1);
        }

        $offset = ($this->get_page() - 1) * $this->get_per_page();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Post` limit $offset, $num_off";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        // display
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $tuts[] = $row;
        }
        // count nums
        $sql = 'select count(post_id) from Post';
        $query = $this->query($sql);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        $this->closeDb();
        return $tuts;
    }

    function paginate() {
        $next = 0;
        echo " <div class = \"pagination\">
               <ul>";
        if ($this->get_page() > 1) {
            $prev = $this->get_page() - 1;
            echo " <li><a href = \"posts.php?page=$prev\">Prev</a></li>";
        } elseif ($this->get_page() == 1) {
            $prev = $this->get_page();
            echo " <li class=\"disabled\" ><a href = \"posts.php?page=$prev\">Prev</a></li>";
        } else {

        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->get_total_page(); $i++) {
            $id = $i;

            echo " <li><a href = \"posts.php?page=$id\">$i</a></li>";
        }
        if ($this->get_page() < $this->get_total_page()) {
            $next = $this->get_page() + 1;
            //var_dump($next);
            echo " <li><a href = \"posts.php?page=$next\">Next</a></li>";
        } else {
            echo " <li class=\"disabled\"><a href = \"posts.php?page=$next\">Next</a></li>";
        }



        echo "</ul>
        </div> ";
    }

    function post_title($param) {
        if ($param == NULL) {
            echo "title";
        } {
            echo $param;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It's usually better to provide reviewers with a bit of context; tell us what your code is doing, what aspects of it you're concerned with. This will help you decide which answer to accept when you get answers :)

Answer (score 2):

If the code will be distributed, read or maintained by others, you might want to look at your naming conventions as they're a bit inconsistent, for example sometimes you use underscore separated names such as `get_per_page()`, but other times you use sulkingCamelCase such as `postByCats()` and `Posts()` in class case. Either one is fine, as long as you use the same throughout.

Aside from your single line getters and setters, the function names you've chosen are not always indicative of what the function does. Ideally you shouldn't have to read the actual code to know what a function does, consider these changes:

```
function counts($cats)
function getNumberOfPostsForCategory($category)

function cats()
function getCategories()
```

You also haven't got any access modifiers on your methods. As `paginate()` directly prints out a segment of HTML which wouldn't be valid on its own, I'm guessing that it's probably only used once somewhere in your View and as such should be `private` or `protected` to prevent misuse.

As for the actual code, aside from collapsing some statements there's not much to change. These lines in `paginate()` don't appear to be doing anything though:

```
$sql = 'select count(post_id) from Post';
$query = $this->query($sql);
```

In addition to the empty `else` statement in the `Posts()` method.